# Type Error 'numpy.float64' has no len() that I can't work out, Convince Python it is dealing with an array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am currently writing a script that converts the measured magnitudes of a galaxy inside an aperture into luminosities. I am using Jupyter Notebooks with Python 3 and numpy. I am also propagating uncertainty in the measurements through the second function below.

When I look to call the `luminositieserror` function, the error returned is:

`TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float64' has no len().`

The code I am using is as follows:

```
#converts an array of magnitudes, a_mag, into an array of luminosities
def m_to_L(a_mag, g_dist, abs_s_mag):

      list1 =[]

      for i in range(len(a_mag)):
        ans = 10**(-0.4*(a_mag[i] -5*np.log(g_dist) -5 -abs_s_mag))
        list1.append(ans)

       return np.array(list1)

#converts an array of magnitude uncertainties, a_mag_err
#into an array of luminosity uncertainties, by calculating 
#uncertainty due to each variable in m_to_L and then adding
#them in quadrature, for every index in the array a_mag
def Luminosity_errors(a_mag, a_mag_err, g_dist, g_dist_err, abs_s_mag, abs_s_mag_err):


    list1 =[]

    for i in range(len(a_mag)):

        alpha_mag = abs(m_to_L((a_mag[i] + a_mag_err[i]), g_dist, abs_s_mag) - m_to_L(a_mag[i], g_dist, abs_s_mag))

        alpha_dist = abs(m_to_L(a_mag[i], (g_dist + g_dist_err), abs_s_mag) - m_to_L(a_mag[i], g_dist, abs_s_mag))

        alpha_solar = abs(m_to_L(a_mag[i], g_dist, (abs_s_mag + abs_s_mag_err)) - m_to_L(a_mag[i], g_dist, abs_s_mag))

        ans = (alpha_mag**2 + alpha_dist**2 + alpha_solar**2)**0.5

        list1.append(ans)

    return np.array(list1)
```

I then call the function on well defined variables:

```
luminositieserror = Luminosity_errors(appmagnitudes, appmagerror, g_dist, g_dist_err, abs_s_mag, abs_s_mag_err)
```

With the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-7a37ab3a0861> in <module>
----> 1 luminositieserror = Luminosity_errors(appmagnitudes, appmagerror, g_dist, g_dist_err, abs_s_mag, abs_s_mag_err)

<ipython-input-32-96474bd06045> in Luminosity_errors(a_mag, a_mag_err, g_dist, g_dist_err, abs_s_mag, abs_s_mag_err)
     14     for i in range(len(a_mag)):
     15 
---> 16         alpha_mag = abs(m_to_L((a_mag[i] + a_mag_err[i]), g_dist, abs_s_mag) - m_to_L(a_mag[i], g_dist, abs_s_mag))
     17 
     18         alpha_dist = abs(m_to_L(a_mag[i], (g_dist + g_dist_err), abs_s_mag) - m_to_L(a_mag[i], g_dist, abs_s_mag))

<ipython-input-32-96474bd06045> in m_to_L(a_mag, g_dist, abs_s_mag)
      3     list1 =[]
      4 
----> 5     for i in range(len(a_mag)):
      6         ans = 10**(-0.4*(a_mag[i]-5*np.log(g_dist)-5-abs_s_mag))
      7         list1.append(ans)

TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float64' has no len()
```

From what I understand, I think I need to convince Python that the dummy variable `a_mag` is in fact an array. Any advice on how to do this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you include a `print(appmagnitudes)` in the question?

Comment: You don't convince python of anything. It knows exactly what it's dealing with. You're approaching the error with the wrong mindset; it's you, not the interpreter, that is incorrect

Comment: Python is working with what you give it. If you give it a float, then there is no way you can convince it that it's an array because it simply isn't one

Comment: Don't loop over NumPy arrays when you can avoid it: use vector-wise calculations instead.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your function, so that it works with both NumPy arrays and (scalar) floats (notably, it will not work with lists: you'll have to convert those to an array first):

```
def m_to_L(a_mag, g_dist, abs_s_mag):
    lum = 10. ** (-0.4 * a_mag - 5 * np.log(g_dist) - 5 - abs_s_mag)
    return lum
```

As you can see, this is also much shorter, and you can essentially replace your function call with the middle line in the main code.

Similar for `Luminosity_errors`.

Answer (score 0):

A `float64` object is a `numpy` scalar.  While it has many `ndarray` properties, it is not an array, and does not have a `len`:

```
In [69]: x = np.float64(12)                                                                                                
In [70]: x                                                                                                                 
Out[70]: 12.0
In [71]: x.shape                                                                                                           
Out[71]: ()                # 0d shape
In [72]: len(x)                                                                                                            
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-72-a7f4a5366567> in <module>
----> 1 len(x)

TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float64' has no len()
In [73]: x[()]              # it can be indexed with an empty tuple                                                                                      
Out[73]: 12.0
```

Another way of making a 0d array:

```
In [74]: y = np.array(12,float)                                                                                            
In [75]: y                                                                                                                 
Out[75]: array(12.)
In [76]: y.shape                                                                                                           
Out[76]: ()
In [77]: len(y)                                                                                                            
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-77-24c1855bc88d> in <module>
----> 1 len(y)

TypeError: len() of unsized object
```

But it too doesn't have a `len`.

Direct iteration doesn't work either:

```
In [78]: for i in x: print(i)                                                                                              
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-78-c1c708d34f18> in <module>
----> 1 for i in x: print(i)

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable
In [79]: for i in y: print(i)                                                                                              
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-79-b6e658ea7a00> in <module>
----> 1 for i in y: print(i)

TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array
```

===

There are ways of making sure the array object is iterable, such as making sure it is 1d:

```
In [83]: z=np.atleast_1d(12.)                                                                                              
In [84]: z                                                                                                                 
Out[84]: array([12.])
In [85]: z.shape                                                                                                           
Out[85]: (1,)
In [86]: len(z)                                                                                                            
Out[86]: 1
In [87]: for i in z:print(i)                                                                                               
12.0
```

====

BUT, your code tries to iterate twice on `amag`.  It is assuming then that `amag` is at least 2d.

```
def Luminosity_errors(a_mag, ....:
    for i in range(len(a_mag)):
        alpha_mag = abs(m_to_L((a_mag[i] ....

def m_to_L(a_mag, g_dist, abs_s_mag):
      for i in range(len(a_mag)):
        ans = 10**(-0.4*(a_mag[i] ...
```

In other words, the last line is trying to use `appmagnitudes[i][j]` on the `appmagnitudes` sent to `Luminosity`.

```
In [92]: mags = np.array([1.,2.,3.,4.])                                                                                    
In [93]: mags[0]                                                                                                           
Out[93]: 1.0
In [94]: len(mags[0])                                                                                                      
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-94-d70c4034220e> in <module>
----> 1 len(mags[0])

TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float64' has no len()
```

for a 2d `mags`:

```
In [95]: mags = np.array([[1.],[2.],[3.],[4.]])                                                                            
In [96]: mags.shape                                                                                                        
Out[96]: (4, 1)
In [97]: len(mags[0])                                                                                                      
Out[97]: 1
```